# TypeScriptの配列インデックスにある"+"(プラス記号)は何を表す？

Tags: typescript, angular

Angular(stable v8.2.9)のチュートリアル[入門 - ルーティング - ルーティング情報を使う - セクション3](https://angular.jp/start/routing#%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E6%83%85%E5%A0%B1%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86)をさらっています。下記のソースコードが載っているのですが、３行目の"+"はどういう意味があるのでしょうか。
"+"を除いてもうまく動作しているように見えます。

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    this.product = products[+params.get('productId')];
  });
}
```

「配列、インデックス」に加えて、演算子、アノテーションなどで調べてみたのですがよくわからず…。"+"にはどういう効果・意味があるのか、お教えいただけませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

おそらくですが、number型へのcast(変換)です。

```js
// 文字列の前に + を付けるとnumber型が返る
const str = '0';
const num = +'0';

console.log(str + 1);
console.log(num + 1);
```

例えば他にも以下のような方法があります。

JavaScriptにおける数値⇔文字列の型変換あれこれ - console.lealog();
https://lealog.hateblo.jp/entry/2013/02/28/005010

> ```js
> var str = '123';
>
> +str; // 123
> -(-str); // 123
> ~~str; // 123
> str&-1; // 123
> str|0; // 123
> str^0; // 123
> str>>0; // 123
> str<<0; // 123
> ```

余談ですが、ビット演算によるnumber型への変換の場合、結果が32bitの整数になることに注意してください。

```js
console.log(+'1.10');

console.log(~~'1.10');
console.log('1.10'&-1);
console.log('1.10'|0);
console.log('1.10'^0);

console.log('1.10' >> 0);
console.log('1.10' << 0);

console.log('1.10' >>> 0);
```

32bitの範囲を超える数値の場合、意図しない結果になります。

```js
console.log('2147483647' | 0);
console.log('2147483648' | 0);

console.log('2147483647' >> 0);
console.log('2147483648' >> 0);

console.log('4294967295' >>> 0);
console.log('4294967296' >>> 0);
```

ビット演算子 - JavaScript | MDN
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: キャストだったのですね。`0 + '1'→"01"`、`'0' + 1→"01"`、`+ '1'→1`となりました。

Answer (score 5):

MDN では **単項正値演算子** という名称で説明されていました。
[#単項演算子　式と演算子 - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Unary_operators)

この演算子が文字列に対して使用された場合、

- 数値に変換可能な文字列であった場合は数値
- 数値に変換不可能であった場合は [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

に変換されます。

また、[#数値　JavaScript 「再」入門 - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Numbers)では、
[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) や [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) との違いが説明されており、

> parseInt() および parseFloat() 関数は文字列を、規定の数値書式に該当しない文字が現れるまで解析し、その箇所までの数値を返します。一方、"+" 演算子は適切でない文字を含む文字列を NaN に変換します。

と書かれています。
実際に以下の様に実行することで違いが分かります。

```js
console.log(parseInt("10.2abc"));   // 10
console.log(parseFloat("10.2abc")); // 10.2
console.log(+"10.2abc");            // NaN
```